# How do I create a button dynamically based on user input?

Tags: android, button, dynamic, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make an app where the user types in text and presses enter and a button is dynamically placed on a different activity with its text set as what the user inputs. I am not sure how to do this, I was thinking of saving the user input in a sharedPreference but I am not sure where to go from there.

```
package com.example.opisa;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddGoalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create object of SharedPreferences.
    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
    //now get Editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goals);
    }
    public void addGoalText(View view) {
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (name.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            mText.setText("Didnt type anything");
        } else {
            mText.setText(name.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    //put your value
     editor.putString("goals", name);
    //commits your edits
     editor.commit();

}
```

After the user types in what he wants,I would like the mText to be the value of text on a button that dynamically appears on a different activity.

Answer (score 0):

In Your First Activity Write

```
public class AddGoalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create object of SharedPreferences.
    SharedPreferences setValue ;
    //now get Editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor valueEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goals);
        setValue  = getSharedPreferences("key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public void addGoalText() {
        
        valueEditor = setValue.edit();
        EditText name = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (name.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            mText.setText("Didnt type anything");
            valueEditor.putString("key","Didn't type");
        } else {
            mText.setText(name.getText().toString());
            valueEditor.putString("key", String.valueOf(name.getText()));
        }
        valueEditor.apply();
    }
}
```

> If you are calling addGoalText somewhere , if not use onchangelistener

In Your Second Activity in which you have button

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences setValue ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);// your layout
        setValue  = getSharedPreferences("key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Button your_button =findViewById(R.id.buttonId);//write your own ID
        String S = setValue.getString("key","defaultValue");
        your_button.setText(S);
    }
    
}
```